# How can i use dynamicType to do "perform(selector:)" in swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamictype

In some case: The tableView has more than one type of UItableViewCell and these cells implement the function "setData(_:)". 
So, in the

```
"tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell".
```

I can use 
`"perfrom(selector:)"` 
to avoid "swift  type conversion (like
`if indexPath.row == 1{ cell as! SomeCoustomCell })".`
But if i use 
`"#selector()"`
i still need konw the type of cell and use 
`"SomeCoustomCell.setData(_:)".` 
Thus, i solved it by use 
`"cell.perform(Selector("setData:"), with: dataSource[indexPath.row]["data"])"`
Although it has a warning.

[image]
What's the correct way in swift??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `perfrom(selector:)` is not the best way. You could use a **protocol**. Something like

```
protocol Configurable{
    func setData(_ data: String)
}
```

All your custom tableView cells should conform to this protocol.  Then in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

```
if cell is Configurable{
    cell.setData(data)
}
```